# Is it currently more cost effective/efficient to run a general purpose parallel algorithm on an accelerated quantum simulator or on CPUs?

Tags: performance, quantum-parallelism

Quantum simulation is advancing and I'm wondering if now or in the future there is a point where its more cost effective and efficient to run general purpose parallel algorithms (e.g. with a mix of operations, loops, conditional flows and highly parallel tasks etc) on an hardware/GPU/analogue accelerated quantum simulator, or will it be always better on CPUs?

Answer (score 3):

We are not at the point where quantum computers are outperforming classical computers in any practical way so certainly not now. As for the future, there already exist numerous algorithms which have been shown to theoretically outperform classical computers so once the hardware catches up we should be in a good place to take advantage of it.

Regarding the cost effectiveness, there was a [recent assessment](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2107.05362.pdf) which looked at the operating costs of running [Google's quantum supremacy calculation](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-019-1666-5) on a QC and a classical computer and they estimated the following:

For the classical computer, we obtain: $$ 60 h * 13 000 kW * $0.1/kWh = $78,000. $$
For the quantum computer, we obtain: $$ 0.056 h * 25 kW * $0.1/kWh = $0.14. $$

Edit:

Following up with your comment, while simulating a quantum computer you need to hold every complex amplitude in memory. Since this has an exponential scaling, it isn't possible to do this efficiently on a classical computer. For example, if you have $N$ qubits then you need to store in memory $2^N$ complex amplitudes which quickly becomes infeasible for even our most powerful supercomputers. Feynman discussed this early on and you read about it in [section 3: simulating probability.](http://physics.whu.edu.cn/dfiles/wenjian/1_00_QIC_Feynman.pdf) Given this type of scaling, you won't be able to access the power of a quantum computing algorithm using GPU's over CPU's, but perhaps you can get some speedups.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, I was actually looking for something more related to simulation of quantum computers. If simulation is efficient enough to be more efficient that classical computing, then we can start writing quantum computing algorithms to get direct benefits now, thats the idea i'm thinking of.

Comment: I edited my response to hopefully answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

> "I was actually looking for something more related to simulation of quantum computers. If simulation is efficient enough to be more efficient that classical computing, then we can start writing quantum computing algorithms to get direct benefits now, that's the idea i'm thinking of."

Since classical simulation of quantum computers on non-quantum hardware, falls under the category of classical computing, it is impossible for it to become "more efficient" than classical computing, because it's an *example* of classical computing, meaning that classical computing will be able to offer something *at least* as efficient (in the worst case the classical algorithm can be simply the simulation of the quantum computer on a classical computer, which is what you started with in this comparison).

> "The current response does not actually answer the question. I want to understand the efficiency of parallel algorithms via quantum simulation on accelerated hardware Vs CPU, not on actual quantum computers."

You have given GPUs as an example of "accelerated hardware", and I suppose you're aware of other types of "accelerated non-CPU hardware" such as FPGAs and ASICs. All of those examples of "accelerated hardware" are examples of classical computers, and yes they do vastly outperform ordinary CPUs in many cases, even for the simulation of the quantum mechanics going on in quantum computers. However there is not one example where simulating a quantum computer on a classical device (whether it be a CPU or "accelerated hardware" such as GPUs) leads us to a more efficient way to solve a problem than just solving the problem directly on a classical device.

Comment: The point I'm trying to understand is whether or not quantum simulation should be our go to for general purpose parallel processing, as if its good enough its worth coding up quantum algorithms over classical ones as quantum tech is advancing fast. Ofcourse if you code up a specific low level implementation directly on an accelerated device, this will outperform the quantum simulation, but this in an expensive process.

Comment: Can you think of one reason why quantum simulation should be our go to for general purpose parallel processing?

Comment: Its good preparation for when quantum computing hits the mainstream. Why not code quantum algorithms amd have them run efficiently now in simulation then when quantum hardware becomes readily available just switch over.

Comment: @newlogic Simulating them efficiently will have no bearing on their efficiency on the real quantum hardware when the switch is made!

Comment: Using simulation now is useful if its just as good if not better than parallel processing on CPU, and when the switch is made the we simpy get the performance of the quantum hardware?

Comment: @newlogic Simulating a quantum computer on a classical computer, is ***not*** just as good as parallel processing on a CPU, for any algorithm apart from simulation itself. For example, simulating Shor's algorithm on a classical computer would be an extremely expensive and inefficient way to factor numbers compared to using the GNFS with parallel processing on a CPU. Simulating Grover's algorithm on a classical computer would be *exponentially* worse than just doing standard parallel (or even serial!) processing on a CPU.

Comment: I notice you have only 19 hours left on the bounty, and you've asked a lot of follow-up questions. Are you satisfied with the answers here to your follow-up questions? I'm also willing to continue answering whatever left-over questions you have, even after the bounty expires (but only to a reasonable extent, based on the amount of time I have available).

Comment: Do you have references for this? I feel that a parallel algorithm simulated on an accelerated device should be able to outperform a CPU for the same cost

Comment: I will help you with that, but I'm at work right now and won't be able to reply during the 40 minutes left on the bounty. I'll try to reply tonight when I'm done my office work.